# PHP Form Refusing to Submit, Cause of Error Unknown

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

TLDR; I repurposed a PHP Registration/Login script to fit my needs. Now, I'm having errors. My initial purpose is to create a homework log, yes, but in retrospect, this is also a learning experience for me, improving on my PHP, as my knowledge on it is fairly poor. I understand that this post may appear vague, but I can't find the solution on my own, so I've come here for assistance.

> The error is the form simply won't submit and it displays the error
>   message to me which is configured in the coding. I tried removing this error,
>   and messing around with it in other ways, but nothing worked. In my mind, what
>   dignifies something as an error should be set by the coder, no?

So, I'm attempting to create a homework log that I can update through a form. I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I have enough knowledge of coding to take on this project at the very least. Due to my lack of PHP coding skills, I instead found a PHP Registration/Login form, which I then re-purposed to my needs. I feel as if I've done everything correctly, and can't seem to find the error, so I've come here. I've read over the code multiple times, and trying many solutions but to no avail.

Here's the initial PHP Code:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$error = false;

if ( isset($_POST['btn-signup']) ) {

    // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
    $course_name = trim($_POST['course_name']);
    $course_name = strip_tags($course_name);
    $course_name = htmlspecialchars($course_name);

    $period = trim($_POST['period']);
    $period = strip_tags($period);
    $period = htmlspecialchars($period);

    $teacher = trim($_POST['teacher']);
    $teacher = strip_tags($teacher);
    $teacher = htmlspecialchars($teacher);

    $date_assigned = trim($_POST['date_assigned']);
    $date_assigned = strip_tags($date_assigned);
    $date_assigned = htmlspecialchars($date_assigned);

    $date_due = trim($_POST['date_due']);
    $date_due = strip_tags($date_due);
    $date_due = htmlspecialchars($date_due);

    $description = trim($_POST['description']);
    $description = strip_tags($description);
    $description = htmlspecialchars($description);
    // if there's no error, continue to signup
    if( !$error ) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO homework_assignments(course_name, 
                                                   period, 
                                                   teacher, 
                                                   date_assigned, 
                                                   date_due, 
                                                   description) 

                                                   VALUES(
                                                   '$course_name', 
                                                   '$period', 
                                                   '$teacher', 
                                                   '$date_assigned', 
                                                   '$date_due', 
                                                   '$description', )";
        $res = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);

        if ($res) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
            unset($course_name);
            unset($period);
            unset($teacher);
            unset($date_assigned);
            unset($date_due);
            unset($description);
        } else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";   
        }   

    }


}
?>
```

Right before this issue, I had a previous error relating to MySQL_Query being discontinued, and I obviously was able to find the solution to this, but I'm not convinced it's correct, seeing as it only posed a new error.

Here's that line of code:

```
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

The dbconnect.php also had similar errors, but I also 'fixed' those, and still wondering if I made a mistake.

Here's the dbconnect.php file:

```
     <?php

    // this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
    error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
    // but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.

    define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
    define('DBUSER', 'root');
    define('DBPASS', '');
    define('DBNAME', 'school');

    $conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);
    $dbcon = mysqli_select_db($conn, DBNAME);

    if ( !$conn ) {
        die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_error());
    }

    if ( !$dbcon ) {
        die("Database Connection failed : " . mysqli_error());
    }
```

The warning message at the top is from the original developer, but, due to my limited knowledge I don't actually understand how to fully transform it to that, or if I did it already. I have tried to refer to the manual, but, it's simply a manual, not a guide, which is why I've come here to ask help from the experience community.

EDIT 1: After fixing some silly typos, and reviewing the original code back to mine, I successfully managed to stop the error. The system is fully functioning now.

Comment: Please add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after `error_reporting` and try again. Tell us if you see any error and post it in your answer as "EDIT 1".

Comment: This fixed the error in the initial, unedited code, meaning the form as it was before I touched it. I boiled it down to having something to do with the "unset" function. I also found that a section of the PHP wasn't needed for my purpose, so I removed it, and functionality remained successful on the unedited version. Here's that version: (I'll add it as Edit 1, as it's too long.)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Sorry. Have you seen my answer?

Comment: I now realize how crazy that response sounded, after actually understanding what your answer meant. I applied multiple solutions at once, and thought yours was the one that made it work.

Comment: "_how crazy that response sounded_"... My or yours? :-)) In the end, all that matters is that your problem were solved ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Oh, my response, of course. And yeah, I should really stop neglecting learning PHP. I took the laziest route here.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your sql insert statement (an extra comma at the end of values bracket):

```
'$date_assigned', 
'$date_due', 
 '$description', )";
```

If you have any other issues with database connectivity, you can echo the function `mysqli_connect_error()` to know what was that. It prints the entire error message.

And yes, as one comment on the question says, also add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after `error_reporting`, so you can see the usual php error messages too. An alternative way is to use `error_log()` function to write debug messages on the php console.

Answer (score 0):

1) Replace `$dbcon` with `$conn` in the line with `mysqli_query`. So, it must be:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Otherwise you are receiving error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given

2) In sql statement you must delete the last comma. It must be:

```
... '$description' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answers, plus a few additional pieces of code I initially missed but managed to find on my own, helped me solve this issue.

> There is an error in your sql insert statement (an extra comma at the
>   end of values bracket):
>
> ```
> '$date_assigned', 
> '$date_due', 
> '$description', )";
> ```
>
> If you have any other issues with database connectivity, you can echo the function `mysqli_connect_error()` to know
>   what was that. It prints the entire error message.

---

> add
>   `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`; after `error_reporting`

---

> 1) Replace `$dbcon` with `$conn` in the line with mysqli_query.